# Hold epic in Redux Observable until action is received

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm new to rxjs and redux-observables

I have two epics:

```
export const appInit = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(actions.appInitRequest)
  .take(1)
  .switchMap(() => actions.fetchData())
```

and

```
export const navigation = ($action, {getState}) =>
  $action.ofType(actions.locationChange)
  .do(console.log)
```

App Init fires action to fetch data,
Is it possible to hold the navigation epic till the fetch data complete? so if navigation action received and fetch data didn't complete we'll wait till fetch data complete (dispatch action.fetchDataSuccess) and than continue the navigation epic flow?

I tried the following code but than every request after the fetchDataSuccess waits for new fetchDataSuccess

```
export const navigation = ($action, {getState}) =>
  $action.ofType(actions.locationChange)
    .switchMap(({payload: {pathname}}) =>
      $action.ofType(action.fetchDataSuccess)
      .take(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html):

```ts
export const navigation = ($action, {getState}) =>
  $action.ofType(actions.locationChange)
    .withLatestFrom(appInit)
    .filter(([locationChangeEvent, appInitEvent]) => {
      return /* check that app inited successfully */
    })
    .map(([locationChangeEvent]) => locationChangeEvent)
    .do(console.log)
```